# Failed To Setup Chaquopy in my Android project, Annotation Problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle, chaquopy

[image: The Error]
So basically when I sync my project with the gradle with the chaquopy. I am unable to declare the function

I am expecting that the gradle sync is successful and I am able to start working on the project as soon as possible.

this is my build.gradle.kts (:app) based off [this gradle](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/blob/master/demo/app/build.gradle.kts) found in chaquopy's own github repository.

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.chaquo.python")
}

afterEvaluate {
    val assetsSrcDir = "src/main/assets/source"
    delete(assetsSrcDir)
    mkdir(assetsSrcDir)
    for (filename in listOf("python/chaquopy/mediaPipe/main.py",
        "java/com/example/createzero/MainActivity.kt")) {
        val srcFile = file("src/main/$filename")
        if (! srcFile.exists()) {
            throw GradleException("$srcFile does not exist")
        }
        copy {
            from(srcFile)
            into(assetsSrcDir)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.createzero"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.createzero"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

//        val plugins = buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath")
//            .resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.map {
//                it.moduleVersion.id
//            }.filter {
//                it.group == "com.chaquo.python" && it.name == "gradle"
//            }
//        if (plugins.size != 1) {
//            throw GradleException("found ${plugins.size} Chaquopy plugins")
//        }
//        versionName = plugins[0].version
//
//        val verParsed = versionName!!.split(".").map { it.toInt() }
//        versionCode = verParsed[0] * 1000000 +
//                verParsed[1] * 1000 +
//                verParsed[2] * 10

        ndk {
            abiFilters += listOf(
                "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
            )
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        resourceConfigurations += "en"
    }

    buildTypes {
        create("releaseMinify") {
            initWith(getByName("release"))
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    lint {
        disable += "ValidFragment"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

chaquopy {
    defaultConfig {
        // Android UI demo
        pip {
            install("Pygments==2.2.0")  // Also used in Java API demo
        }
        staticProxy("chaquopy.demo.ui_demo")

        // Python unit tests
        pip {
            // We use an old version of murmurhash (built from the Chaquopy branch
            // `murmurhash-0`), because in newer versions, importing murmurhash
            // automatically imports and extracts murmurhash/mrmr.so, which would
            // complicate the tests.
            install("murmurhash==0.28.0")  // Requires chaquopy-libcxx

            // Because we set pyc.src to false, we must test extractPackages via pip.
            install("../../product/gradle-plugin/src/test/integration/data/" +
                    "ExtractPackages/change_1/app/extract_packages")
        }
        extractPackages("ep_bravo", "ep_charlie.one")
        staticProxy("chaquopy.test.static_proxy.basic",
            "chaquopy.test.static_proxy.header",
            "chaquopy.test.static_proxy.method")
        pyc {
            // For testing bytecode compilation on device, and also to include test
            // source code in stack traces.
            src = false

            // For testing bytecode compilation during build.
            pip = true
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")


    //splash
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.1.0-alpha02")



}
```

and this is the build.gradle.kts (project) file

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "14.0.2" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `chaquopy` syntax requires Chaquopy 15, which will be released in the next few days.

Meanwhile, you can use a pre-release build by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/934#issuecomment-1683205265):

> - At the top level of your project, edit the settings.gradle or build.gradle file to add this line to the `repositories` block within `pluginManagement` or `buildscript` (NOT within `allprojects` or `dependencyResolutionManagement`):
>
>   ```
>   maven { url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven-test") }
>   ```
> - Edit the build.gradle file to change the Chaquopy version to `15.0.0`.

For more details, see the [Chaquopy 15 documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/15.0/android.html).

Comment: Thankyou, it worked, so I can not get mediapipe installed using pip, I keep getting this error ```Chaquopy: Installing for armeabi-v7a
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0, https://chaquo.com/pypi-13.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)```

Comment: For updates on MediaPipe, please subscribe to https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/479.